# Collection/Dictionary.Count returning a different value to the actual number of elements?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I'm probably missing something obvious - but when I do `.Count` on a Dictionary or a Collection I'm getting the wrong count compared to the actual number of elements in the Dictionary or Collection.

I have code that counts the number of words in a string, and returns a `Collection<KeyValuePair<string, uint>>`.

Here's my code:

```
string myString = String.Format("Hello world this is test test test test hi");

var result = WordCounter.GetWordCollection(myString);

result.Dump(); //Using LINQPad .Dump() method

Console.WriteLine ("Counted {0} words in {1}ms", result.Count, stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);

foreach (var word in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", word.Key, word.Value);
}
```

Result:

[image]

What's going wrong?

Edit: I was counting the number of unique words without realising it, like the comment/answer said. I needed to use `result.Sum(n => n.Value)`.

Comment: And what does `GetWordCollection` return?  It's of course easy enough to create your own collection type that returns whatever you want.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: It returns Collection<KeyValuePair<string, uint>>

Comment: `Count` in this case is giving you the number of unique words.  You need `Sum` to get the total.

Comment: Well thanks for the downvotes, not everyone is an expert.

Comment: Sum is the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working properly - there are seven keys in the dictionary, each with a value representing how many times they were in the source text. The count of seven means there are seven unique words. Summing the values will give you the total word count including repetitions.